# What is the effect of manipulation of a function over its domain range and graph?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, planar-graphs

Suppose I have a function f of x another function G of x which is derived by manipulating f of x. Domain of f is D1 and its range is R1 whereas domain of G is D2 and range is R2. Now what can we said about domains, ranges and graphs. Will they be exactly same or almost same with except at some points. Please make this clear.
EDIT1:
https://pasteboard.co/ISG3HPa.jpg
Attaching this image over my analysis, please tell is the conclusion is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulating $f(x)$? My guess is that you mean $G(x)$ only depends on $f(x)$ - a way to formalise that is to say that $G=g\circ f$ - i.e. a composition of $f$ with another function $g$ - however it is not clear to me if *that* is what you mean.

Comment: For example f(x) is (cosx)^2 - (sinx)^2 . Then g(x) can be cos2x which came after manipulation of f(x).

Comment: Ah, ok ... this makes it quite an open-ended question, because you did not explain which steps are allowed in "manipulation". Many formal steps that people use to manipulate formulas make for *slightly* (or not so slightly!) different formulas. Of course, $(\cos x)^2-(\sin x)^2=\cos(2x)$ - exactly the same function, but what if you want to square the function, and then take the square root? Or if your function is $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ which is almost the same as $f(x)=1$ ... except it is not defined at $x=0$ (while the latter one is)... [tbc]

Comment: [Cont'd] ... even if all you did was to cancel $x$. Altogether, I think I cannot answer this question without you providing the list of allowed "manipulations" and then we can study them one by one.

Comment: @StinkingBishop see this analysis is this correct, https://pasteboard.co/ISG3HPa.jpg , actually its a broad classification with no need of categorization of manipulations.

Comment: Then, can you please edit the question first to reflect what you are *actually* asking, e.g.: "Provided that two functions $f:D_1\to R_1, f(D_1)=R_1$ and $g:D_2\to R_2, g(D_2)=R_2$, match on the common domain ($f(x)=g(x)$ for $x\in D_1\cap D_2$), are the following statements correct: <please paste the content from your image, formatted in MathJax>?" At least I *guess* this is what you *really* want to ask.